# Pykka: get the base class of an Actor

Tags: python, actor, pykka

I use [pykka](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pykka) python library. I would like to create an actor, and later test if the actor created is of the proper class.

```
class MyActor( ThreadingActor ):
  # ...

actor = MyActor.start().proxy()

assert actor.__class__ == MyActor # check here?
```

Here `actor.__class__` is `pykka.actor.ActorRef`. How to check if it refers to `MyActor` class? I need it for a unit test suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the actor class from an `pykka.actor.ActorRef`:

```
ref = MyActor.start()
assert ref.actor_class == MyActor
```

To get the actor class from an `pykka.proxy.ActorProxy`:

```
proxy = MyActor.start().proxy()
assert proxy.actor_ref.actor_class == MyActor
```

I've forgotten to document the `actor_class` field on `ActorRef` objects, but all fields that are not made "private" by prefixing with underscore will continue to be supported in the future.

Comment: I've updated the [documentation](http://pykka.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#pykka.actor.ActorRef.actor_class). It now includes the `ActorRef.actor_class` attribute.